# multi connection java utility

Tags: java, database-connection

I have a utility that is used for opening connection also for selecting etc.. - the connection is global variable 
my problem is when i have multi connection - i am getting failure ,with an error "connection is null" - the problem is that when the first instance is ending it is closing the connection and the second instance for some reason is using the first instance's connection.

can any body find what is wrong ?

this is my code

*readPropertiesByName(dbName) is just use to get populate the gDataSource which is global

```
public void initDBByName(String dbName) throws SQLException, NamingException 
{
    readPropertiesByName(dbName);
    InitialContext initialContext=new InitialContext();
    Context context=(Context)initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/");
    DataSource dataSource=(javax.sql.DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/" + gDataSource);
    this.connection =dataSource.getConnection();
    this.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

here is an example of a e query that is using the global connection :

```
public  ResultSet executeSqlQuery(String sqlQuery) throws SQLException
{
    this.connection.createStatement();
    Statement sqlStatement = this.connection.createStatement();
    return sqlStatement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
}
```

Comment: somewhere down your code maybe you are closing your connection, which code uses your executeSqlQuery method?

Comment: You should open and close a connection in the shortest scope necessary. It looks like you are sharing that `this.connection`, which is something you shouldn't do. But without more context it is hard to tell.

Comment: @johnll,yes i am closing the connection in a closeConeection method that is called from the outside but like i wrote i have 2 instance of this util and i expect that only the relevant connection will be closed, same out side instance is calling the executeSqlQuery